# repair file system by edit the fstab file

Tags: redhat, kernel, xfs, fstab

is it possible to run xfs repair by re-edit the fstab file?

```
/dev/mapper/vg-linux_root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=7de1dc5c-b605-4a6f-bdf1-f1e869f6ffb9 /boot   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg-linux_var /var                     xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg-linux_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

I am not sure but by replace the last number from 0 to 1 , is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of ***fstab*** should be  :

```
(Device)  (MountPoint) (FsType) (MountOptions)  (Dump) (FsCheck)
```

So here FsCheck field can take one of the below values :

0 : fsck is disabled

1 : fsck is enabled with more priority ( mainly for root filesystems )

2 : fsck is enabled for other filesystems with less priority.

So you have to choose one of these options.

Comment: The manual site die.net states that fsck on xfs returns without doing anything, it does not run xfs_repair.  https://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck.xfs

Answer (score 0):

No, a positive passno (6th fstab field) is not sufficient. Yes, it still should be 1 for `/` and 2 otherwise.

Specific to XFS, `fsck.xfs` by default does not do anything. Journal recovery at mount may get it into a usable state. But if that fails, the system won't boot, usually requiring booting a rescue target to recover.

> However, the system administrator can force [fsck.xfs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fsck.xfs.8.html) to run
>   [xfs_repair(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/xfs_repair.8.html) at boot time by creating a `/forcefsck` file or booting
>   the system with "fsck.mode=force" on the kernel command line.